# unwanted column width in tabular

Tags: tables

I want to draw the following table
[image]

And I have used this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Image}  & \multirow{2}{*}{Actual Entropy} & \multirow{2}{*}{Encrypted Entropy} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Correlation coefficient plain}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Correlation coefficient encrypted}\\ 
        \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} 
    &  &  & XXXX & XXX & XXXX& xx \\ 
         \hline
  Barbara gray & xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx& xxx\\ 

Bridge  & yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy& xx\\ 

Goldhill  &  zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz& \\ 

Mountain  &  zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz& \\ 

zelda  &  zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz& \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using the above example I got the below output.[image]
But this table consuming unwanted column widths.So How to reduce the column width of the outut table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify multirow cell width manually (they are essentialy `p` column) and set multicolumn as `p`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
    \multirow{3}{*}{Image}  & \multirow{3}{1.5cm}{\centering Actual Entropy} & \multirow{3}{2cm}{\centering Encrypted Entropy} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering Correlation coefficient plain}& \multicolumn{2}{|p{3.2cm}|}{\centering Correlation coefficient encrypted}\\ 
        \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} 
    &  &  & XXXX & XXX & XXXX& xx \\ 
         \hline
  Barbara gray & xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx& xxx\\ 

Bridge  & yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy& xx\\ 

Goldhill  &  zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz& \\ 

Mountain  &  zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz& \\ 

zelda  &  zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz& \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

so to have a table which is similar to the one you posted.

[image]

I also had to change multirow lines from `2` to `3` to adjust to the new height of the table.

P.s.: please excuse the quality of the screenshot, it will look much better on your machine

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in standard cells without having to specify a width. I also a more professional-looking variant without any vertical rule and varying width horizontal rules with `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, booktabs}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{Image} & \multirowcell{3}{Actual\\ Entropy} & \multirowcell{3}{Encrypted\\ Entropy} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{Correlation\\ coefficient plain}}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{Correlation\\ coefficient encrypted}}\\
    \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7}
                 & & & XXXX & XXX & XXXX & xx \\
    \hline
    Barbara gray & xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx & xxx \\
    Bridge & yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy & xx \\
    Goldhill & zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz & \\
    Mountain & zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz & \\
    zelda & zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\setcellgapes{1pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
    \multirowcell{3}{Image} & \multirowcell{3}{Actual\\ Entropy} & \multirowcell{3}{Encrypted\\ Entropy} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Correlation\\ coefficient plain}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Correlation\\ coefficient encrypted}}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                 & & & XXXX & XXX & XXXX & xx \\
    \midrule
    Barbara gray & xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx & xxx \\
    Bridge & yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy & xx \\
    Goldhill & zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz & \\
    Mountain & zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz & \\
    zelda & zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]